# flutter consumer not rebuilding widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, consumer, flutter-change-notifier

consumer widget is not called after data is updated in provider of ChangeNotifier  class in release mode, the same code is working fine in debug mode, and first time in release mode but if the screen is called with pushReplacement it's not rebuild the consumer widget, its building other consumer widget of the same page

Comment: try `flutter clean` and build again. also make sure about `notifyListner`

Comment: Please share your code as well to get better answer.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I tried flutter clean  and also notfiyListener is there , I am using one future builder inside consumer builder

Comment: `FutureBuilder` build just onetime, you may need `StreamBuilder` in your scenario

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have 4 `consumer` in that page  and all have `FutureBuilder` in it only one consumer not working fine in release  mode other three are working and I am uing same code logic for all